# Error when using rpy2 to call the R script in Django:UnicodeDecodeError, invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, r, django, rpy2

I am using a Django development server that requires rpy2 to call the R script, but there is an error:

**UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd4 in position 40: invalid continuation byte**

Python code is

```
        try:
            robjects.r.source("static/R/Sequence.R")
        except Exception as e:
            message={"status":1,"error":str(e)}
            return JsonResponse(message)
        try:
            robjects.r.sequence(PACds,getup,getdown)
        except Exception as e:
            message={"status":0,"error":str(e)}
            return JsonResponse(message)
```

R code is

```
  library(movAPA)
  library(BSgenome)
  library("BSgenome.Oryza.ENSEMBL.IRGSP1")
  sequence<-function(PACds,up,down){
  bsgenome=getBSgenome(genome = "IRGSP1")
  faFiles=faFromPACds(PACds=PACds,bsgenome=bsgenome,what='updn',up=up,dn=down,fapre='sq')
  plotATCGforFAfile(faFiles, ofreq=FALSE, opdf=TRUE, 
                     refPos=301, mergePlots = TRUE,filepre='Download/seq')
}
```

Comment: Indicating which line in the R code is triggering the error, as well as sharing the Python traceback, whether the issue is only present with Django, what are the Python, R, and rpy2 version used would help readers decide whether they might have an answer.

Comment: Did you find a solution so far? I also experience this error when converting a R data frame back to a Panda dataframe via `rpy2.robjects.conversion.rpy2py()`.